# combos dependientes y botón resultado

Tags: javascript, html, select

Estimados amigos, estoy implementado unos combos dependientes utilizando este ejemplo dejo url  y código. mas abajo.

los combos funcionan bien usando el ejemplo, lo que necesito es incorporar a esa funcionalidad un botón de resultados que dependiendo del filtro de selecciones muestre el contenido, tengo 2 ideas o cargue un archivo externo, un html. o tal vez pueda ser una listas de ID, y mostrar o ocultar los ID de acuerdo al filtro.

es la idea que tengo y lo que tengo implementado, como mencione necesito incorporar un botón que filtre los resultados de acuerdo a lo seleccionado en los combos o select.
¿o tal vez si hay un mejor opción también se puede realizar?

dejo el ejemplo usado.

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mfuusp9p/

```js
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          countySel.options[0].text = "Please select state first"
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        countySel.options[0].text = "Please select county"
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
        if (countySel.options.length==2) {
          countySel.selectedIndex=1;
          countySel.onchange();
        }  
        
    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        citySel.options[0].text = "Please select city"
        
        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
        if (citySel.options.length==2) {
          citySel.selectedIndex=1;
          citySel.onchange();
        }  
        
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Hola no he podido adaptar el alert a lo que quiero podrías ayudarme con un ejemplo mas detallado, como comento si es posible cargar html externo por filtro o se podría mostrar o ocultar un div con su id por cada filtro. creo que ya entendiste la idea pero no puedo lograrlo. por favor dame una mano gracias.

Comment: ¿Con el botón deseas mostrar «qué cosa»? ¿Resultado de qué? ¿Información de la ciudad?

Answer (score 1):

Primero coloca un boton al final del formulario XD. Segundo, yo usaria jquery, te va a facilitar mucho las cosas.

En este caso, lo que he hecho es:

Colocar una funcion a filtrar al boton.
La funcion llama a tus select por nombre (lo haria por ID, pero por no modificartelo).
Los he guardado en unas variables y he hecho alert de ellas para que veas de manera sencilla como obtenerlas. Ahora tienes simplemente tienes que manejarlas.
Cualquier otra cosa no dudes en preguntar. Espero haberte sido de ayuda :)

---

### EDITADO

Prueba a usar los id de los divs por ejemplo para llamar a las funciones hide() y show(). De esta manera los mostraras y los ocultaras segun te convenga.

```js
var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          countySel.options[0].text = "Please select state first"
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        countySel.options[0].text = "Please select county"
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
        if (countySel.options.length==2) {
          countySel.selectedIndex=1;
          countySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        citySel.options[0].text = "Please select city"

        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
        if (citySel.options.length==2) {
          citySel.selectedIndex=1;
          citySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
}

function filtrar(){
  var state = $('[name="optone"]').find(":selected").index();
  
  if(state==1){
    $('#California').show();
    $('#Oregon').hide();
  }else if(state==2){
    $('#Oregon').show();
    $('#California').hide();
  }else{
    $('#California').hide();
    $('#Oregon').hide();
  }
    var country = $('[name="opttwo"]').find(":selected").index();
    var city = $('[name="optthree"]').find(":selected").index();
  alert(" state: "+state+" country: "+country+" city: "+city);
}
```

```css
#Oregon, #California{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="filtrar()" value="FILTRAR"/>
</form>
</div>
<div id="California">
  <h1>CALIFORNIA</h1>
  <p>California es uno de los cincuenta estados que, junto con Washington D. C., forman los Estados Unidos de América. Su capital es Sacramento y su ciudad más poblada, Los Ángeles.</p>
</div>
<div id="Oregon">
  <h1>OREGON</h1>
  <p>Oregón es uno de los cincuenta estados que, junto con Washington D. C., forman los Estados Unidos de América. Su capital es Salem y su ciudad más poblada ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: hola necesito hacerlo con 6 id he logrado hacerlo con 3, como seria para mostrar u ocultar 6 gracias.

Comment: tu ejemplo va como quiero pero esta dependiendo de state la idea es que dependa de country y me muestre mas citys.

Comment: Aplica lo mismo pero al combo que tu quieras, edita el id y la llamada. Yo te he peusto el primero como ejemplo.

Comment: Hola te deje unos comentarios y mi código real podrías ayudarme . es urgente

Answer (score 1):

ya esta ya me funciona el alerta, pero me dan un idea, que es mejor quiero cargar mediante el botón por cada filtros html externos es posible, por cada filtros son diferentes html, como se podría hacer.

o tambien puede ser mostrar o ocultar divs por id.

Gracias.

por ejemplo se tiene los códigos, como hago para que en vez del alert() cada vez que seleccione una combinación y al dar al botón filtrar me haga block o show cada id y muestre su contenido.
Gracias.

```js
 var stateObject = {
    "California": {
        "Monterey": ["Salinas", "Gonzales"],
        "Alameda": ["Berkeley"]
    },
    "Oregon": {
        "Douglas": ["Roseburg", "Winston"],
    }
}
window.onload = function () {
    var stateSel = document.getElementById("stateSel"),
        countySel = document.getElementById("countySel"),
        citySel = document.getElementById("citySel");
    for (var state in stateObject) {
        stateSel.options[stateSel.options.length] = new Option(state, state);
    }
    stateSel.onchange = function () {
        countySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          countySel.options[0].text = "Please select state first"
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        countySel.options[0].text = "Please select county"
        for (var county in stateObject[this.value]) {
            countySel.options[countySel.options.length] = new Option(county, county);
        }
        if (countySel.options.length==2) {
          countySel.selectedIndex=1;
          countySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
    stateSel.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
    countySel.onchange = function () {
        citySel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
          citySel.options[0].text = "Please select county first"
          return; // done   
        }  
        citySel.options[0].text = "Please select city"

        var cities = stateObject[stateSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
            citySel.options[citySel.options.length] = new Option(cities[i], cities[i]);
        }
        if (citySel.options.length==2) {
          citySel.selectedIndex=1;
          citySel.onchange();
        }  

    }
}

function filtrar(){
  var state = $('[name="optone"]').find(":selected").index();
    var country = $('[name="opttwo"]').find(":selected").index();
    var city = $('[name="optthree"]').find(":selected").index();
  alert(" state: "+state+" country: "+country+" city: "+city);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select name="optone" id="stateSel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="opttwo" id="countySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select state first</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select name="optthree" id="citySel" size="1">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Please select county first</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="filtrar()" value="FILTRAR"/>

</form>

 <div id="primero" style="display:none;">Primer Contenido</div>

        <div id="segundo" style="display:none;">segundo Contenido</div>

        <div id="tercero" style="display:none;">Tercer Contenido</div>
```

te dejo mi código original ojala puedas ayudarme. el contenido del HTML no imparta solo es para que veas los id, te dejo el código que tengo son 6 ID que debe mostrar y ocultar, lo hace con el combo 2 pero solo en el código si ves puede hacerlo hasta 3, no puedo mostrar mas de 3 ID no se por que fíjate los combo.

```js
var stateObject = {
     "Fija": {
         "Alta Nueva": ["¿Conoces el plazo de atención de un pedido Trio o Dúo?"],
         "Migración": ["¿Sabes que es una Migración?"],
         "Traslado": ["¿Sabes qué es un TRASLADO?"]
     },
     "Móvil": {
         "Cambio de plan": ["¿Cómo me cambio de plan?"],
         "Cambio de equipo": ["¿Cómo cambio de equipo en tienda?", "¿Cómo cambio de equipo de forma on line?"]
     },
     "Avería": {
         "Fija": ["¿Cuál es el plazo de atención para una avería en el servicio fijo (Línea básica) por teléfono? ", "¿Cuál es el plazo de atención para una avería en el servicio fijo (Línea básica) presencial?"],
         "Internet": ["¿Sabes cuál es el plazo de atención para una avería en el servicio de internet?"],
         "Cable": ["¿Sabes cuál es el plazo de atención para una avería en el servicio de cable o bloque HD?"]
     }
 }
 window.onload = function () {
     var cmbRed = document.getElementById("cmbRed"),
         cmbProducto = document.getElementById("cmbProducto"),
         cmbConsulta = document.getElementById("cmbConsulta");
     for (var red in stateObject) {
         cmbRed.options[cmbRed.options.length] = new Option(red, red);
     }
     cmbRed.onchange = function () {
         cmbProducto.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         cmbConsulta.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
           cmbProducto.options[0].text = "Seleccione una opción"
           cmbConsulta.options[0].text = "Seleccione una opción"
           return; // done   
         }  
         cmbProducto.options[0].text = "Seleccione una opción"
         for (var producto in stateObject[this.value]) {
             cmbProducto.options[cmbProducto.options.length] = new Option(producto, producto);
         }
         if (cmbProducto.options.length==2) {
           cmbProducto.selectedIndex=1;
           cmbProducto.onchange();
         }  
         
     }
     cmbRed.onchange(); // reset in case page is reloaded
     cmbProducto.onchange = function () {
         cmbConsulta.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
         if (this.selectedIndex < 1) {
           cmbConsulta.options[0].text = "Seleccione una opción"
           return; // done   
         }  
         cmbConsulta.options[0].text = "Seleccione una opción"
         
         var consulta = stateObject[cmbRed.value][this.value];
         for (var i = 0; i < consulta.length; i++) {
             cmbConsulta.options[cmbConsulta.options.length] = new Option(consulta[i], consulta[i]);
         }
         if (cmbConsulta.options.length==2) {
             cmbConsulta.selectedIndex=1;
             //cmbConsulta.onchange();
         }  
         
     }

 }
  
  
  
  function filtrar(){
var red = $('[name="red"]').find(":selected").index();
indice = document.getElementById("cmbRed").selectedIndex;
if( indice == null || indice == 0 ) {
alert("Debe Seleccionar una opción");
return false;
}
var producto = $('[name="producto"]').find(":selected").index();
 if( indice == null || indice == 0 ) {
alert("Debe Seleccionar una opción");
return false;
}
//MUESTRA INFO FIJA
if(producto==1){
   $('#trio-duo').show();
   $('#migracion').hide();
   $('#traslado').hide();
  }else if(producto==2){
$('#trio-duo').hide();
$('#migracion').show();
$('#traslado').hide();
  }else{
$('#trio-duo').hide();
$('#migracion').hide();
$('#traslado').show();
  }

var consulta = $('[name="consulta"]').find(":selected").index();
if( indice == null || indice == 0 ) {
alert("Debe Seleccionar una opción");
return false;
}
  

}
```

```css
.field {display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <form>
                <ul>
                  <li><span class="titulo-combo">Tipo de red</span>
                    <select class="combo" id="cmbRed" name="red" required>
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione una opción</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li><span class="titulo-combo">Tipo de producto</span>
                    <select class="combo" id="cmbProducto" name="producto" required>
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione una opción</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                  <li><span class="titulo-combo">Tipo de consulta</span>
                    <select class="combo" id="cmbConsulta" name="consulta" required>
                      <option value="0" selected="selected">Seleccione una opción</option>
                    </select>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <input class="btn-continuar" type="button" value="Continuar" onclick="filtrar();">
              </form>

<div id="trio-duo" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Conoces el plazo de atención de un pedido Trío o Dúo?</span><span class="titulo-canales">Canal de atención: </span><span class="iconos-canales">
                          <ul>
                            <li>104</li>
                            <li>Tienda</li>
                            <li>COL</li>
                          </ul></span><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c1.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El cliente solicita su requerimiento<br>en el <b>canal de atención.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c2.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El asesor lo <b>deriva a ventas</b><br>para grabar el pedido.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c3.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Se informa al cliente que<br>se atenderá en un plazo<br><b>de 15 días útiles.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c4.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Dentro del plazo de atención la contrata<br>debe contactar al cliente para <b>agendar</b><br><b>la visita técnica </b>y realizar la instalación<br>del servicio.</span></li>
                          </ul><span class="info-pedido">*Número de pedido asociado al requerimiento es un código de <b>8 dígitos.</b></span></span></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="warapper-infografias">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="migracion" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Sabes que es una Migración?</span>
                        <p>
                           Una migración es cuando el cliente desea realizar <b>un cambio de Plan </b>que supone una modificación en su tarifa y características del Plan según la oferta escogida, <b>manteniendo el mismo número. </b>Existen migración UP, cuando la tarifa aumenta en su cargo y migraciones Down, cuando reduce el cargo fijo mensual. </p><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Conoces el plazo de atención de una migración?</span><span class="titulo-canales">Canal de atención: </span><span class="iconos-canales">
                          <ul>
                            <li>104</li>
                            <li>Tienda</li>
                            <li>COL</li>
                          </ul></span><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c1.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El cliente solicita su requerimiento<br>en el <b>canal de atención.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c2.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El asesor lo <b>deriva a ventas</b><br>para grabar el pedido.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c3.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Se informa al cliente que<br>se atenderá en un plazo<br><b>de 7 a 15 días útiles.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c4.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Dentro del plazo de atención la contrata<br>debe contactar al cliente para <b>agendar</b><br><b>la visita técnica </b>y realizar la instalación<br>del servicio.</span></li>
                          </ul><span class="info-pedido">*Número de pedido asociado al requerimiento es un código de <b>8 dígitos.</b></span></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="warapper-infografias">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="traslado" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Sabes qué es un TRASLADO?</span>
                        <p>
                           Es el cambio de ubicación física del servicio: <b>TRÍO, DÚO. </b></p><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Conoces el plazo de atención?</span><span class="titulo-canales">Canal de atención: </span><span class="iconos-canales">
                          <ul>
                            <li>104</li>
                            <li>Tienda</li>
                            <li style="display:none;">COL</li>
                          </ul></span><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c1.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El cliente solicita su requerimiento<br>en el <b>canal de atención.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c2.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El asesor lo <b>deriva a ventas</b><br>para grabar el pedido.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c3.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Se informa al cliente que<br>se atenderá en un plazo<br><b>de 7 a 15 días útiles.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c4.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Dentro del plazo de atención la contrata<br>debe contactar al cliente para <b>agendar</b><br><b>la visita técnica </b>y realizar la instalación<br>del servicio.</span></li>
                          </ul><span class="info-pedido">*Número de pedido asociado al requerimiento es un código de <b>8 dígitos.</b></span></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="warapper-infografias">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="cambio-de-plan" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Cómo me cambio de plan?</span>
                        <p>
                           Un cambio de plan supone una <b>modificación en la tarifa mensual y/o características del plan. </b>
                          El titular de la línea puede autogestionarlo
                          a través de la zona privada MI MOVISTAR, además de gestionarlo vía el call center 104, desde el dispositivo móvil.
                          El plazo de atención es en función al requerimiento puntual, debería atenderse durante el tiempo en que está en línea el cliente.
                        </p><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c1.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Cliente llama al <b>104.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c2.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Asesor <b>valida </b>datos y<br><b>atiende </b>requerimientos.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/c3.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Asesor informa respecto el <b>estado</b><br><b>de la transacción </b>y comunica que<br>el cambio se verá reflejado en<br>el siguiente ciclo de facturación. </span></li>
                            <li style="display:none;"></li>
                          </ul></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="warapper-infografias">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="equipo-tienda" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Cómo cambio de equipo en tienda?</span>
                        <p> 
                          Un cambio de equipo gestionado en la tienda Presencial, debería atenderse durante el plazo en que el cliente se encuentra con el asesor.
                          El equipo puede financiado de acuerdo a la <b>evaluación de riesgo </b>que realiza el asesor y condiciones de venta.
                        </p><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/01_t.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Cliente visita la <b>Tienda.</b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/02_t.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Selecciona el <b>equipo </b>y solicita <br>el <b>CAEQ </b>de acuerdo a la información<br>brindada por el Asesor.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/03_t.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Asesor <b>valida </b>transacción y<br><b>stock </b>en el almacén. </span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/04_t.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Finalmente el cliente se lleva<br>el equipo <b>asociado al plan. </b></span></li>
                          </ul></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="warapper-infografias">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div id="equipo-online" class="field"><span class="titulo-infografia">¿Cómo cambio de equipo de forma on line?</span>
                        <p>
                           Un cambio de equipo gestionado en el <b>canal on Line, </b>
                          supone el despacho vía delivery del equipo. El cliente deberá llenar todos sus datos
                          en la web, vía los formularios asociados en el catalogo de equipo.
                        </p><span class="caja-info">
                          <ul>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/01_o.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Cliente ingresa al link<br><a href="http://www.movistar.com.pe/">http://www.movistar.com.pe/</a></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/02_o.jpg"></span><span class="text-info"><b>Selecciona el equipo, completa</b><br>los datos en el formulario asociado<br>y luego lo envía.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/03_o.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El equipo de ventas se contactará<br>con el cliente en un plazo no mayor<br>a <b>24 horas. </b>Valida y graba la venta.</span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/04_o.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">Se coordina con el cliente la entrega<br>del equipo, <b>sólo por delivery. </b></span></li>
                            <li><span class="img-info"><img src="images/05_o.jpg"></span><span class="text-info">El pago se realizó via <b>POS o tarjeta.</b><br>No se acepta efectivo.</span></li>
                          </ul></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: hola alguien que podría ayudarme con esta solución.

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, usa hide y show con condiciones para mostrar lo que quieras. Es decir si estado=1 mostramos div 1. Mira a ver si te vale.

Comment: deje un nuevo ejemplo es mas complejo croe lo revisaste, o te dejo mi código original, en realidad, tengo un problema lo necesito para el combo country como te dije me funciona pero como te explico me funciona para 3 resultados, cuando intento saca mas no me sale nesecito mostrar 6 o 7. ID

Comment: te voy a dejar mi código original y lo que tengo

Comment: explico la idea, el combo red, tiene 3 categorías, se puede ver en el objeto, Fija, Móvil, Avería, esto tres salen el combo red. luego en le combo productos salen dependiendo si escojas Fija, muestra: Alta nueva, migración, traslado. esta parte con las condiciones lo hace correcto, oculta los id y muestra correctamente. pero al cambiar de categoría y escoger por ejemplo en red Móvil, tendría que poder mostrar y ocultar cambio de plan y cambio de equipo. y al seleccionar en red; Avería; Debe mostrar: fija Internet y cable. esa es la lógica

Comment: cuando me refiero devén mostrar son los ID de los divs y hacer show o hide a cada div.

Comment: fíjate en mi ejemplo, hazlo funcionar, te darás cuenta si encojes Fija, te salen 3 opciones en el combo productos alta nueva, migración y traslados, esto sale al dar al botón filtrar lo hace bien. esto mismo deveria pasar la escoger Móvil y averías, pero no logro hacerlo como comente solo he podido hacerlo con 3 IDS, falta los demás, he probado varias formas y no lo he logrado.

Comment: No se a lo que te refieres exactamente, por lo que estoy entendiendo, yo lo veo bien:
EJ: -Fija-Alta Nueva-¿Conoces el plazo de atención de un pedido Trío o Dúo? // Se printa bien, y asi sucesivamente con todos. Todos printan lo que deberian. Coloca algun pantallazo de lo que quieres sino, porque creo que no llegamos a entendernos en esta parte.