# ¿Cómo mostrar contenido en un div según un dropdown-menu en bootstrap 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

¿Cómo le puedo hacer para mostrar contenido en un div según la opción que haya elegido?

Si elijo la opción  de info2 que me muestra una información determinada  a la opción que selecciono, igual que si elijo info3 me muestre otra información diferente y así sucesivamente

Este es mi código de dropdown

```html
<div class="btn-group dropup" >

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Copiar</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"  >
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
       
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      
          <h6 class="dropdown-header"> Información </h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 1</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 2</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 3</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 4</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 5</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item"  >Info 6</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: echale un ojo al siguiente código: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/80078/combos-dependientes-y-bot%C3%B3n-resultado/80087#80087

Comment: ¿Quieres hacerlo en Javascript puro o estas usando JQuery o algun otro framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tu código, asumo que estás trabajando con bootstrap 4.

Un dropdown es un conjunto de enlaces, no es como un combobox donde una opción se selecciona (fíjate que el botón "Copiar", no cambia a menos que lo programes).

Como son enlaces, podemos agregarle un evento de click para mostrar y/o ocultar elementos, para ello he usado jQuery.

Fíjate que he agregado un atributo a cada enlace que es `data-target` que contendrá el selector del contenedor a mostrar, esto es para no agregarle un evento individual a cada enlace, en este caso estoy usando el id `#info-n`, con ello cuando le hace click, le quito la clase `active` a todos los elementos para que se oculte el actual y le agrego la clase active solo al`div` del `data-target`.

```js
$('[data-target]').click(function() {
  const target = $(this).data('target');
  $('.info').removeClass('active');
  $(target).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}

.info.active {
  display: block;
}


/*Algunos estilos*/
.infos {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: #666 solid 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="btn-group">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Copiar</button>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>

  <div class="dropdown-menu">

    <h6 class="dropdown-header"> Información </h6>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-1">Info 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-2">Info 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-3">Info 3</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-4">Info 4</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-5">Info 5</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" data-target="#info-6">Info 6</a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="infos">
<div id="info-1" class="info active"> Info 1 </div>
<div id="info-2" class="info"> Info 2 </div>
<div id="info-3" class="info"> Info 3 </div>
<div id="info-4" class="info"> Info 4 </div>
<div id="info-5" class="info"> Info 5 </div>
<div id="info-6" class="info"> Info 6 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya funciona perfectamente @Ali. Pero ahora tengo otro problema. ó que me puedes sugerir. estoy haciendo una consulta a mi base de datos, y me muestra mis "cards"  con una información muy resumida entonces tengo un boton para abrir un modal ese modal tiene mas información acerca de ese  producto seleccionado. pero entonces implemente lo que me dijiste del dropdown ya que según una opción  me muestra ciertas cosas que quiero, todo bien hasta ahí. Pero quise abrir otro modal  de otro producto" Y si le pongo info1. info2,  no me sale nada. solo funciona con el primer modal. no se si me explique.

Comment: Los id's solo se pueden declarar una sola vez, si los declaras más veces, el `getElementById` solo obtiene el primero, en mi ejemplo yo usé id's para los `info-n`, por lo que si está mostrando y ocultando los info, pero del primer modal, para solucionarlo, contempla el uso de clases o el uso de ids diferentes para cada modal.